# Ext.js: How to add a search bar to a panel's header?

Tags: javascript, extjs

in Ext.js, how to add search bar to a panel's header? There is a ext.panel.tool class, but none of them are search bar. There is only a "search" button, what I need is add a text input field together with a search button into a panel's header.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141239/how-can-i-put-a-dropdown-in-the-header-of-an-extjs-panel?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
 Ext.onReady(function() {

    Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.SearchField', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.field.Trigger',    
        alias: 'widget.searchfield',    
        trigger1Cls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'form-search-trigger',          
        initComponent: function(){
            this.callParent(arguments);
        },      
        afterRender: function(){
            this.callParent();          
        }
    });

   Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Hello',
    width: 700,   
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    tools: [ {
        xtype: 'searchfield'
     }]
   });

});
```

Please find more details about `searchField` source code [Here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/ux/form/SearchField.js)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use icons in panel you have to use type config otherwise you can use search field component which is basically textfield component with search bar styling .

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
title: 'Search',
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
tools: [{
        xtype: 'searchfield'
    }, {
        type: 'search'
    }
]
});
```